# Zipping bundle via Automator

Tags: automator, zip

I am looking for a way to zip a fcpx bundle with an Automator service. Automator won't accept a bundle as an input for a service (zip, rename and copy to two different locations for backup purposes), neither as a file or directory. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here - a "bundle" of *what* exactly?  Do you want an Applescript or a bash/script?  That's two distinct questions.  See, [How To Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in our [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/)

Comment: Hello jschrey, welcome to Ask Different. When you write "bundle", do you mean an application bundle (that, is a .app executable)? You seem to be asking two distinct questions (I know, both are about zipping a bundle, but that's the only thing in common): zipping a "bundle" with a service and getting a watched folder to recognize a "bundle". I'd recommend that you post two questions, and elaborate more on what you troubleshooting you have done, the error message you are getting (if any), how the service is supposed to work and how the watched folder is set up (AppleScript? Automator?)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. By bundle I mean an fcpxbundle. The service I'm I'd like to create should do the following: zip the bundle, add a date and some text and copy the zip-file to two different folders (local and cloud service) for backup purposes. For some reasons Automator doesn't see the bundle as a valid input sometimes, sometimes it works just fine. No error messages.

Comment: Hi! Great clarification in the comments. This is too broad since there might be different answers for how to get Automator to work vs terminal. Would you edit this to have one question and include the bundle clarification? An edit by you will trigger a review to release the temporary hold.

Comment: You should also include your Automator workflow in the question.

Comment: Got it working by starting out a new workflow, no idea what caused the original hiccup. Here's the working service https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=kZ2HxD7Z2XJuhOSxhCzNJoVqHIIL9Sy9JgV7

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to define a watched folder that selects all, compress (zip), rename the archive.zip file, copy for another locations and erase all to wait new files. If the automator action is not working properly you could try using applescript to use Finder commands. For instance open the folder using Finder and run the script:

```
set numberOfFiles to number of files in folder (((path to desktop folder) as text) & "YourFolder") 
tell application "Finder"
    activate
end tell
tell application "system events"
    keystroke A using command down -- select all
    tell process "Finder"
          click menu item "Compress " & numberOfFiles & " Items" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

After that carry on with your actions to rename, copy and delete.

Comment: So someone downvoted my idea but didn't state the reason. What is the purpose of this system? I feel like everybody around here is trying to screw me for nothing. All this rules just make me sad and unmotivated to keep trying to help. This community is mean and unfriendly.

Comment: You're wrong but this might be useful for other stuff. Will try out. Thanks